# JPanel repaint() method and debugging

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jpanel, paint

So I have created a small window with a ball bouncing around on it in Java and was trying to debug and watch the program work. Heres the important code for the question:

```
public class Ball {
private static final int SPEED = 2;
private int x = 0, y = 0;
private int xInc = SPEED, yInc = SPEED;

-> public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
} 
}


public class Game extends JPanel {

Ball gameBall = new Ball();

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // cleans the panel
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    gameBall.paint(g2d);

}

public void updateBall() {
    gameBall.move(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Simple Pong");
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Game gamePanel = new Game();
    mainFrame.add(gamePanel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    while (true) {
        try {
            gamePanel.updateBall();
            gamePanel.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
      }

    }

  }
```

I set a method pointer for the entrance of the paint method of Ball, thinking it would cause the program to halt each time the repaint() method is called, since I thought it calls the paint method. Then, I could watch the ball move one increment at a time instead of placing a line pointer where the repaint method is.

When I do this, the program does not halt with each update of the placement of my ball, and instead halts in what seems like random increments. The ball will be close to the edge, then in the middle so many calls to paint had to of occured.

Question: Does the repaint method always call the paint method for my lightweight container? And if so, why does the debugger not halt with each increment of the ball and instead only halt to display the new position sometimes? Obviously if the ball is moving smoothly on the screen while running, something is painting the Ball object onto my Game Panel exactly as I would like it to.

Note: The same thing happens if we place a method breakpoint for the entrance of the paint method for Game, which I have extending JPanel and is what I paint the ball onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`repaint` does not directly call `paint`.* It just sets a variable so that Swing will, at some point, remember to call `paint`.

Now, do you know about threads? Because the explanation of what's happening here involves threads.

Everything to do with Swing usually runs on one thread, called the "event thread". In particular, `paint` gets called on the event thread.

`main` is called on a thread called the "main thread". The main thread is not the event thread. Your `main` method moves the ball (indirectly, by calling `updateBall`). The main thread's code is roughly "move the ball, set the 'repaint me later' variable, repeat".

When your breakpoint is hit, only the thread that hit the breakpoint is paused. That means the event thread is paused. The main thread, which updates the ball's position, continues running. The ball's position keeps getting updated while you think the program is paused (because actually only one thread is paused).

When you unpause the event thread, the event thread will go back to doing what it was doing (i.e. painting). Since, by now, the "repaint me later" variable will have been set, it will paint the game panel again - but the ball will have moved quite far this time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting very aggravated. You really couldn't have answered my question any more clearly.

Comment: @immibis Just one more thing, if the main method is actually still running and only the event thread is paused, what is going on with the methods that run on the event threat located IN the main method such as repaint?

Comment: @bmcentee148 `repaint` will be calling the `RepaintManager` requesting updates to be made, it's possible the the `RepaintManager` may ignore some of them, but it's likely that the repaint requests are been added to the `EventQueue`, waiting for the EDT to become unblocked and process them.  It might be possible for the `RepaintManager` to "remove" pending request, but I don't recall seeing this mechanism the last time I was digging around that part of the code...This could result in your paint methods been hammered in quick succession once the EDT is unblocked...

Comment: @bmcentee148 There is no such thing as a cross-thread method call. `main` gets called on the main thread, and it calls `repaint`, so those particular `repaint` calls run on the main thread. Usually this is a no-no (because it usually works, but sometimes it doesn't, and it can lead to hard-to-track bugs), but `repaint` is one of the functions you're allowed to call on any thread.

Comment: Okay so those calls to repaint in the main thread are not actually displayed on the panel while the event thread is held up. How does that actually work? It seems as they are just passed over because the faster I click the play button, the close the ball appears to its last position. From this I take it the main thread is definitely updating its position just not displaying it even though calls the the repaint method are being made on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the repaint method always call the paint method for my lightweight container?

No.  Calls to `repaint` are requests for an update.  The repaint manager may optimise the requests and consolidate them down into a single event if it can.

Swing uses a passive painting algorithm which is designed to improve performance for systems which don't need to repainted all the time, painting only when it needs to be done.

On a side note, you should avoid overriding `paint` of components and instead prefer using `paintComponent`.  Also beware, the `Graphics` context passed to your paint methods is shared with everything else been painted, making changes to it might have undesirable side effects.

Instead, you should create a snapshot of the `Graphics` context's state and modify it...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D g2d)g.create();
//... Update, modify, transform, do what you want...
g2d.dispose();
```

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Swing operates in a single thread.  That is, all painting and even notification is done within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

When you hit your break point, the Event Dispatching Thread is STOPPED, but the `while-loop` you have running is not, so the x/y position of the `Ball` is still been updated, meaning that when the program resumes, the ball will appear to "jump" to a new location.

You can test this by placing a breakpoint on `gamePanel.updateBall();`, the UI will continue to be update (after each request to `repaint`), but will incrementally update as, as the state of the ball is not been altered.

The debugging process is not stopping the other threads that are running, but only effecting the thread from within which the breakpoint was triggered.

When Java calls you `main` method, it is doing so from what is known as the "main thread".  When you call `setVisible` on your `mainFrame`, a new thread is created (the Event Dispatching Thread), this allows the UI to run independently on the `while(true)`, preventing it from "hanging" the UI.  Check out [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: So then how does the program know where to place the ball if my overridden method isn't being called?

Comment: It's an illusion. There is enough of a change between frames to allow the ball to "appear" to move...that's the essence of animation...

Comment: Anyone wish to highlight the cause of the downvote so I might learn from your observations or even maybe fix something I've done wrong?

Comment: But when run the ball moves smoothly across the screen as expected. Debugging, it appears from place to place and NOT IN SMALL INCREMENTS. Why is the paint method...which is the only thing that have instructions for where to place my ball... only occur randomly yet appear to be called every frame.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I downvoted you for not answering the question, unless I've misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @immibis Sorry, I think I see your point, thanks for the clarification ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer No problem and thanks for the clarification. My apologies also as I did not see your second response until now. Just reworked my code to use `paintComponent` and am also using a snapshot of my `Graphics` obj and disposing of it at the end of `paintComponent`. Everything seems to work exactly as before which is great, but would you mind explaining a little as to why this is the safer approach for the `Graphics` obj?

Comment: The `Graphics` context is a shared resource, that is, all the components painted during a given paint cycle will receive the same `Graphics` context and on some platforms, the same `Graphics` context is used through the lifetime of the containing window.  Making modifications like, transformations or composites or rendering hints will remain with the `Graphics` context, meaning they will affect everything else painted (and yes, I've watched antialiasing render hints spread across a screen before, really freaky). Generally, you should reverse these changes before you exit the paint method or...

Comment: Yes a temporary copy of the `Graphics` context, where by you can change it's state, without affecting the original `Graphics` context and simply `dispose` of it when you're finished...they still paint to the same target, you're just isolating the changes